# Accessing outer scope name in a lambda, is g++ or Visual or neither, right?

Tags: c++, lambda

Code:

```
auto main() -> int
{
    int b = 42;
    auto lambasta = [&]()
    {
        using B_type = decltype( b );
        return B_type{};
    };
    (void) lambasta;
}
```

Compiles with no diagnostic with MinGW g++ 6.3.0 `-std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic-errors`. Fails to compile with Visual C++ 2015 update 3,

```
foo.cpp(6): error C2065: 'b': undeclared identifier
```

Comment: Compile even without capture for clagg/gcc [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/002edb55e3a07e00).

Comment: Does `&b` in the capture list work?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: Yes, explicit capture of the name helps Visual C++ understand that it exists. So does actual ODR use of the name (before the mention). Unfortunately that's not a workaround for my original problem, where the name occurs in an expression that is supplied as a macro argument.

Comment: Looks like it was fixed in MSVC 2017 RC (it works with no capture too).

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround:

```
template<typename T>
struct wrapper
{
    using wrapped_t = T;
};

auto main() -> int
{
    int b = 42;
    auto lambasta = [&, a = wrapper<decltype(b)>()]()
    {
        using B_type = typename decltype( a ) ::wrapped_t;
        return B_type{};
    };
    (void) lambasta;
}
```

Works on GCC 6.3 and MSVC 2015 up 3